# nginx virtual hosts not listening to correct hostname

Tags: nginx, web-server, mac-osx

I'm a newbie to nginx, but I encountered a basic problem that is totally not obvious to me.

I installed nginx using brew on my mac. That worked fine, with this basic, unchanged default config:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm a developer working on multiple projects. Previously I configured a virtual host in apache for each of these, combined with a custom hosts entry like `myproject1.local`.

So, to test this with nginx, I edited my /etc/hosts file and added:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   mytestproject.local
```

Then, in the nginx config, I added the following:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen mytestproject.local:80;
    server_name mytestproject.local;

    location / {
        root /Users/MyUserName/Projects/mytestproject/Web;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

With that, I *expected*:

- `http://localhost` should show the default website
- `http://localhost:8080` and `http://mytestproject.local` should show the website from mytestproject.

Instead of that, this is what happened:

- `http://localhost:8080` and `http://mytestproject.local` correctly shows the website from mytestproject.
- **But** `http://localhost` *also* delivers files from the test project, and not the ones from the default website like I expected

So, this is my question:

Where was I wrong? What do I need to configure to have localhost show the default website while anything else on other ports and with other custom domains (via /etc/hosts) show their corresponding content, and not mixing that up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better off moved to StackOverflow.com? As a customer support professional myself I like having a local environment on which to test, but am new to setting this up on a Mac. This seems like a legitimate question for professional developers, although not necessarily professional admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read how nginx chooses server block http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#mixed_name_ip_based_servers.

In you case first server listens to `*:80` and second to `127.0.0.1:80`, and when you go to `http://localhost/` you browser connects to `127.0.0.1:80` and nginx choose second server block because it's better match to request, `Host` header is tested after that.

So simple solution is to replace `listen mytestproject.local:80;` with simple `listen 80;`.

Comment: That nailed it. Thanks. That fact is indeed a bit counter-intuitive, but when you know about it it's okay to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have strange feeling that a Bonjour service has something with that.
Bonjour service do multicast dns for .local domains
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/domainnames.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001072-202537